# Hiding scrollbar but space is still occupied

Tags: html, css

Example: https://codepen.io/ianhd/pen/oNJLBjQ

The scrollbar is successfully hidden, but it's still occupying space. How can I get rid of the space it would normally occupy?

[image: space is still occupied]

```css
.outer {
  width: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #999;
}

.scrollable {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
  scrollbar-width: none;
}

.scrollable::-webkit-scrollbar {
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="scrollable">this is scrollable...</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `::-webkit-scrollbar { display: none; }`

```css
.outer {
  width: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #999;
}

.scrollable {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
  scrollbar-width: none;
}

.scrollable::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="scrollable">this is scrollable...</div>
</div>
```